# Unresolved reference: compose in "coil.compose.AsyncImage"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am trying to import the coil image library inside a composable function using `import coil.compose.AsyncImage` and `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2")` but Android Studio can't recognize the 'compose' and returns

> Unresolved reference: compose

I tried to invalidate the caches and clean the project with no change happened
I use Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 where:

```
compose_ui_version = '1.2.1'

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.1'
}

compileSdk 33
gradle 7.4
```

Comment: Did you add `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")` in your `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes I did implement @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MartyMiller I used Android Studio Electric Eel instead of Dolphin with the same SDK  and the error was gone. I don't know why.
Of course, it's not a solution but I guess it's an issue with the IDE

Answer (score 3):

To use coil library with jetback compose you gotta use the **coil-compose** dependency.

In your `build.gradle`

change this `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2")`

to this  `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")`

Comment: This answer should be accepted. I couldn't figure out the difference of 'coil' and 'coil-compose' until I saw your answer. Ty

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).